# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments getting in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift-playground

I am doing some learning things in swift. And I am using version Swift 4.

I am trying to do some method overriding thing.

```
class cricket {
    func print() {
        print("Super class called")
    }
}

class tennis : cricket {
    override func print() {
        print("Sub class called")

    }
}

let circInstance = cricket()
circInstance.print()

let tennisInstance = tennis()
tennisInstance.print()
```

But, If I would run above program in my playground of Xcode, Getting following error at print statements.

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:508:15: error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments
        print("Super class called")
             ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: MyPlayground.playground:514:15: error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments
        print("Sub class called")
             ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a name conflict with the local method. You have to use the qualified name:

```
Swift.print("Super class called")
```

Otherwise you are trying to call `self.print()` which takes no arguments.

`Swift.` here is the name of the [Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library) module that contains the [print](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) function.

Comment: Thank you, Swift.print() is latest version of swift print statement syntax?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative That would work on all Swift versions since 1.0

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative And if you didn't have a conflicting `print()` method you made, you wouldn't need to do `Swift.print("...")`, and can just do `print("...")`. I would recommend that you change the method name to something like `printClass()` to avoid confusion.